# UnsatisfiedLinkError in Android Studio using Gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, java-native-interface, native

I recently migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio and am having some trouble accessing the native functions. The first native function that is called is nativeClassInit(). Most of what I've seen regarding this question involved a missing "static" identifier, but I've included it in MainActivity.java. I've been trying for a couple of days now and have run out of ideas. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

The System.loadLibrary functions do not return null and I am able to see the app's *.so files when I run  adb shell ls -l package/name/path/lib:

```
-rwxr-xr-x system   system       5096 2015-03-27 18:32 libPixa.so
-rwxr-xr-x system   system     775728 2015-03-27 18:32 libgnustl_shared.so
-rwxr-xr-x system   system   24998736 2015-03-26 15:01 libgstreamer_android.so
```

I am very new to Gradle so feel free to criticize my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sbimagingsystems.pixa"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19

        ndk {
            moduleName "gstreamer_android" // Name of C++ module (i.e. libSeePlusPlus)
            moduleName "Pixa"
            cFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions" // Add provisions to allow C++11 functionality
            stl "gnustl_shared" // Which STL library to use: gnustl or stlport

        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDir 'src'
            res.srcDir 'res'
            assets.srcDir 'assets'

            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
            jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni']      // location of native code files
            //jniLibs.srcDirs = ['jniLibs']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/pinchzoom.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.7-snapshot-with-sources.jar')
}
```

local.properties:

```
gst.dir=/home/android-dev/AndroidDev/Installation/gstreamer
sdk.dir=/home/android-dev/Android/Sdk
ndk.dir=/home/android-dev/AndroidDev/Installation/android-ndk-r9c
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener
{

    private native void nativeInit(); // Initialize native code, build pipeline,
    // etc

    private native void nativeFinalize(); // Destroy pipeline and shutdown
    // native code

    private native void nativePlay(); // Set pipeline to PLAYING

    public native void nativePause(); // Set pipeline to PAUSED

    private static native boolean nativeClassInit(); // Initialize native class:
    // cache Method IDs for
    // callbacks

    // more code

    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("Pixa");
        System.loadLibrary("gstreamer_android");

        nativeClassInit();
    }
}
```

Pixa.c:

```
/* List of implemented native methods */
static JNINativeMethod native_methods[] = {
  { "nativeInit", "()V", (void *) gst_native_init},
  { "nativeFinalize", "()V", (void *) gst_native_finalize},
  { "nativePlay", "()V", (void *) gst_native_play},
  { "nativePause", "()V", (void *) gst_native_pause},
  { "nativeSurfaceInit", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V", (void *) gst_native_surface_init},
  { "nativeSurfaceFinalize", "()V", (void *) gst_native_surface_finalize},
  { "nativeClassInit", "()Z", (void *) gst_native_class_init},
  { "nativeStartRecord", "()V", (void *) gst_native_record_start},
  { "nativeStopRecord", "()V", (void *) gst_native_record_stop}
};

/* Library initializer */
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
  JNIEnv *env = NULL;

  java_vm = vm;

  if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {
    __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Receiver", "Could not retrieve JNIEnv");
    return 0;
  }
  jclass klass = (*env)->FindClass (env, "com/sbimagingsystems/pixa/MainActivity");
  (*env)->RegisterNatives (env, klass, native_methods, G_N_ELEMENTS(native_methods));

  pthread_key_create (&current_jni_env, detach_current_thread);
  return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}
```

and finally, LogCat:

```
02-27 18:06:41.799    8248-8248/com.sbimagingsystems.pixa E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sbimagingsystems.pixa, PID: 8248
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.sbimagingsystems.pixa.MainActivity.nativeClassInit:()Z
        at com.sbimagingsystems.pixa.MainActivity.nativeClassInit(Native Method)
        at com.sbimagingsystems.pixa.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:3197)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
```

to disable automatic NDK build by Android studio. instead build using ndk-build on command line. This would generate your .so files and will be able to link correctly/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that, and when running ndk-build I get the error: android/native_window.h: No such file or directory. Not sure why it can't find the header